# Finding domain of the sum of a series function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives

a. Find the domain of the definition $D \subset \mathbb R$ for the function

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n{x \over n+x}$$

b. For what values of $x\in D$ the function $f$ is differentiable?

My thoughts:

I'm thinking I have to show uniform convergence and be able to use Abel's theorem somehow. Maybe it's easier then that. Not sure, looking for any help. Thanks!

Comment: a.: *Leibniz* series (for a fixed $x$, after a while $n+x>0$).

Answer (score 1):

For a., note that (as Berci pointed out) the series is alternating after sufficiently many terms for any $x$, and so is clearly well-defined provided the first few summands can be considered a small finite contribution, and the rest decay to 0. Is there any problem with this?

For b., uniform convergence is definitely the right way to go - but recall that the precise condition you need is on the convergence of the *derivatives*. For differentiability at each $x$, we freely pick some neighbourhood $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ of the point and ask whether we can do the usual thing: given any $\epsilon>0$, can we choose $N$ such that $|g(y) - \sum_{n=1}^{N} \mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}y (\cdots)| < \epsilon$ for all $y$ in the neighbourhood, for some $g(x)\equiv f'(x)$? That is, can we bound the remainder sum of derivatives independently of where in our neighbourhood we were?